# Flyway V7 kerberos setup

Tags: flyway

I want to know if Kerberos was released in Version 7, I some a few messages saying it is available through database properties, but I couldn't find any information about it. I have a quick look at the code and I found 2 properties flyway.oracle.kerberosConfigFile and flyway.oracle.kerberosCacheFile each I have setup but it continues to ask me for the user password.

Comment: Which edition of Flyway are you using?

Comment: I had download the community edition

Comment: OK - Kerberos support is enterprise-only at the moment.

Comment: Please update the question with all the necessary version (from comments) so that it can help for others later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kerberos support in Flyway 7.0 is only in the paid (Teams) edition. However, you can download a 30-day free licence key for Teams and try it out if you wish to establish whether the paid version offers you the functionality you want. Essentially, setting those two configuration parameters to point to the relevant files (the cache file is optional) is sufficient.

https://flywaydb.org/download/